# How Can I select the face of the similar color in Blender 2.8~2.9?

Tags: python, color, select

When texture painting, sometimes I want to repaint only the certain face with the similar color. Inside of choose the face mannually one by one, is there a way or addon I can do it? Like the PS funtion "Select color".

I've searched on google and find this page https://blenderartists.org/t/select-all-faces-with-same-hex-value-in-edit-mode/592292

which address the same question and some pp solved it by hand-made python scripts. but I believe maybe the code is too old that it doesn't work in 2.8x ~ 2.9X anymore...At least I tried installed the .py addon and tried myself..

And since I know nothing about the python......Anyhelp??